# ConTeXt: Help with leftbottom layer preset

Tags: context, layers

I have a layer that covers the left margin and the text area. The leftbottom preset places the content too high on the page. It is too high by twice the value of y in the layer (in \definelayer, y=20 mm; the content is too high by 40 mm).

[image: leftbottom preset]

```
\showframe

\definepapersize[mypage][height=260mm, width=185mm]
\setuppapersize[mypage] 

\setuplayout
    [backspace=58mm, width=106mm, header=0mm, footer=5mm,  leftmargindistance=5mm, leftmargin=32mm, topspace=20mm, height=220mm, footerdistance=5mm,]

\definelayer % layer covers margin & text area
    [mylayer]
    [x=21mm, width=143mm, 
    y=20mm, height=210mm]

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=lefttop]
    {LEFTTOP}

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=leftbottom]
    {LEFTBOTTOM}

\setupbackgrounds
    [page]
    [background=mylayer]

\starttext
\input lorem
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\showframe

\definepapersize[mypage][height=260mm, width=185mm]
\setuppapersize[mypage]

\setuplayout
     [backspace=58mm,
      width=106mm,
      header=0mm,
      footer=5mm,
      leftmargindistance=5mm,
      leftmargin=32mm,
      topspace=20mm,
      height=220mm,
      footerdistance=5mm]

\definelayer
     [mylayer]
     [width=\dimexpr\leftmarginwidth+\textwidth\relax,
      height=\textheight]

\setlayer
     [mylayer]
     [preset=lefttop]
     {LEFTTOP}

\setlayer
     [mylayer]
     [preset=leftbottom]
     {LEFTBOTTOM}

\setupbackgrounds
     [text] [leftmargin]
     [background=mylayer]

\starttext
     \input lorem
\stoptext
```

[image: layers]

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you originally had seems mostly correct to me, so I'm not too sure where the 40mm discrepancy is coming from.

This seems to work though:

```tex
\showframe

\definepapersize[mypage][height=260mm, width=185mm]
\setuppapersize[mypage]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=58mm, width=106mm, header=0mm, footer=5mm,  leftmargindistance=5mm, leftmargin=32mm, topspace=20mm, height=220mm, footerdistance=5mm, rightmargin=15mm]

\definelayer % layer covers margin & text area
    [mylayer][
        x=\dimexpr\backspace-\leftmarginwidth-\leftmargindistance,
        width=\dimexpr\paperwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth,
        y=\dimexpr\topspace-\headerheight-\headerdistance,
        height=\dimexpr\paperheight-\footerdistance-\footerheight,
    ]

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=lefttop]
    {LEFTTOP}

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=leftbottom]
    {LEFTBOTTOM}

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=righttop]
    {RIGHTTOP}

\setlayer
    [mylayer]
    [preset=rightbottom]
    {RIGHTBOTTOM}

\setupbackgrounds
    [page]
    [background=mylayer]

\starttext
\input lorem
\stoptext
```

[image: sample]

(Aside: your `\textheight` should probably be an integer multiple of your `\baselineskip` to make sure that you fill up the page)

Comment: I don't think that's the answer. Try adding 20 mm to the value for y in the `\definelayer`. The whole layer and its contents should move down 20 mm. The LEFTTOP text does move down 20 mm. But the LEFTBOTTOM text moves up.

Comment: @Stanley Yes, that seems odd to me too. I think the issue may be that the `height` and `width` keys are possibly misnamed: they seem to set the distance between the paper origin (the top left of the paper) and the end of the layer, not the distance between the layer origin and the end of the layer as you would expect. (just guessing)